# How do you attach a popup menu to a column header button in GTK2 using PyGObject?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, pygobject

I want to popup a context menu when the user right-clicks on the header row of a `Gtk.TreeView`. In GTK3, `Gtk.TreeViewColumn` has a get_button() method, which makes this easy; simply attach the menu to the button and connect it to a 'clicked' event. However, in GTK2, this won't work. You can only call a `get_widget()` method, which returns None if you haven't set a widget via `set_widget()`. I've tried putting a `Gtk.Label` with the column name into a `Gtk.EventBox` and set that as the widget After connecting the `EventBox` to a callback for the 'button_press_event', clicking on it doesn't generate the event.

I tried to do something like what's listed [here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/gtk/msg02940.html) but doing `get_parent()` on the column widget returns None, and never reaches the button as their code implies.

What solutions have people found for this?

Comment: I should clarify that by "in GTK2, this won't work", I should have said, "in GTK2, the `get_button()` method wasn't implemented.

Comment: Now I'm also finding out that `menu.attach_to_widget()` and `menu.popup()` apparently are not introspectable in GTK2. According to the [PyGObject site](https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject/IntrospectionPorting), in GTK3 `menu.popup()` was implemented through an override, however I can't find documentation on how this was done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty easy actually, but you need a couple of hacks.

First you need to force Gtk to create a header button for the GtkTreeViewColumn:

```
    label = gtk.Label("Column title")
    label.show()
    treeview_column.set_widget(label)
```

After that you need to fetch the internal GtkButton of the header:

```
    widget = treeview_column.get_widget()
    while not isinstance(widget, gtk.Button):
        widget = widget.get_parent()
```

Finally with a button reference you can do something useful:

```
    def button_release_event(button, event):
        if event.button == 3:
           menu.popup(event)

    widget.connect('button-release-event', button_release_event)
```

This was taken from the [kiwi](http://kiwi.async.com.br/) library which has an [ObjectList](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~stoq-dev/kiwi/master/view/head:/kiwi/ui/objectlist.py) which provides a python list like api for creating GtkTreeViews.

Comment: I'm writing in Perl, but this same approach works.  Thanks!   Of note, I have to add the column to the treeview before calling get_widget.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed seems complicated, I had a look at the [source](http://www.google.com/codesearch#ErvFMsc8kPE/pub/GNOME/sources/gtk+/2.6/gtk+-2.6.4.tar.bz2%7C3rYhbwqyETM/gtk+-2.6.4/gtk/gtktreeviewcolumn.c&q=gtk_tree_view_column_set_widget&type=cs&l=857). Apparently the `parent` trick works (and returns the alignment object), however your custom label is only added to the button after the TreeviewColumn has been realized, so before that the `parent` attribute stays `None` So probably latest after your show command of the Treeview, you should be able to retrieve the parents (Button->HBox->Alignment->Label) and can attach your handler to the signal.

Answer (score 0):

I love working examples on S.O, so I decided to post one. All the credits are for @Johan Dahlin!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk

def button_release_event(button, event):
    if event.button == 3:
        menu.popup(None, None, None, None, event.button, event.time)


window = Gtk.Window()
window.connect("destroy", lambda q: Gtk.main_quit())

liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str)
liststore.append(["1"])
liststore.append(["2"])

menu=Gtk.Menu()
menu.append(Gtk.ImageMenuItem("Yep it works!"))
menu.append(Gtk.ImageMenuItem(":)"))
menu.show_all()

treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=liststore)
window.add(treeview)

treeviewcolumn = Gtk.TreeViewColumn()
treeview.append_column(treeviewcolumn)    

# Set the treeviewcolum as clickable
#
treeviewcolumn.set_clickable(True)

# force Gtk to create a header button for the Gtk.TreeViewColumn
#
label = Gtk.Label("Numbers")
label.show()
treeviewcolumn.set_widget(label)

# fetch the internal GtkButton of the header:
#
widget = treeviewcolumn.get_widget()
while not isinstance(widget, Gtk.Button):
    widget = widget.get_parent()

widget.connect('button-release-event', button_release_event)

cellrenderertext = Gtk.CellRendererText()
treeviewcolumn.pack_start(cellrenderertext, True)
treeviewcolumn.add_attribute(cellrenderertext, 'text', 0)

window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

happy hacking!